# Delphi Templates like C++?

Tags: c++, delphi, templates, pascal

Please, can anyone convert this code for me?

I don't know so much about C++, so I need to convert this code from C++ to delphi:

```
template <typename DestType, typename SrcType>
DestType* ByteOffset(SrcType* ptr, ptrdiff_t offset)
{
        return reinterpret_cast<DestType*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(ptr) + offset);
}
```

Thank you...

Comment: Delphi doesn't have templates and that code cannot be converted directly. To proceed we would need to see how the code is being used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, This code is used in this function: http://pastebin.com/7d9N1J2c "eat_hook"

Comment: While this might seem complicated, this function just adds an offset to a pointer, independently of the pointee type.

Comment: @ereOn, how is it in delphi? thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple to convert, but you can't use templates in Delphi. It is merely adding an offset to a pointer, but the offset is specified in bytes rather than multiples of the pointer base type.

So convert

```
ByteOffset<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS>(DosHeader, DosHeader->e_lfanew)
```

into

```
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(PAnsiChar(DosHeader)+DosHeader.e_lfanew)
```

Some more examples:

```
ExportDirectory := PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY(PAnsiChar(DosHeader)+
    NtHeader.OptionalHeader.
    DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);

functions := PDWORD(PAnsiChar(DosHeader)+ExportDirectory->AddressOfFunctions);
```

and so on.

Comment: Now, can you help me with these codes?


PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY ExportDirectory = ByteOffset<IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY>(DosHeader,
      
`           NtHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);`

and
       
`DWORD* functions = ByteOffset<DWORD>(DosHeader, ExportDirectory->AddressOfFunctions);`

Comment: Use exactly the same pattern. Your first step is to understand what the C++ code does, and why the Pascal code is equivalent. I (or someone else) could do it all for you, but then you would have learnt nothing. I'm sure you can do this!

Comment: David, I guess I undertand I convert the code.. can you see if it's correct?
`
 ExportDirectory := PImageExportDirectory(DWORD(DOSHeader) + DWORD(NTHeaders^.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress));

 functions := DWORD(DWORD(DOSHeader) + DWORD(ExportDirectory^.AddressOfFunctions));`

Comment: That will fail if ever you compile in 64 bit because you will have truncated the pointers. I'll add some more to the answer.

Comment: Alright, I will terminate the convertion and test it. Thank you so much David! s2

Comment: David, and about this code?  `functions[i] = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(new_function) - reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(DosHeader);`  How is it in delphi? thanks

Comment: `functions[i] := DWORD(new_function) - DWORD(DosHeader);` is the literal translation. But that's wrong under 64 bit (pointer truncation again) but then I think the C++ code is 32 bit only anyway. My guess is that you don't want to worry about 64 bit Delphi right now.

Comment: Maybe, but I can't see how you have defined `functions`. I think you have reached the point where you need to ask a new question for this. We've gone quite a long way beyond the original question.

Comment: My 'functions': 
`var 
functions: PDWORD;`

Comment: No, that won't work. You need an array. In this regard Delphi is different from C and C++. But I can't do this in comments. You need to ask a new question purely about how to declare `functions` in Delphi code.

Comment: Hi David, my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484319/converting-a-c-code-to-delphi

Answer (score 3):

Delphi Generics is the closest equivilent to C++ templates, eg:

```
type
  ByteOffset<DestType, SrcType> = class
  public
    type
      PSrcType = ^SrcType;
      PDestType = ^DestType;

    class function At(ptr: PSrcType; offset: NativeInt): PDestType;
  end;

class function ByteOffset<DestType, SrcType>.At(ptr: PSrcType; offset: NativeInt): PDestType;
begin
  Result := PDestType(PByte(ptr) + offset);
end;
```

.

```
var
  I: Integer;
  W: PWord;
begin
  I := $11223344;
  W := ByteOffset<Word, Integer>.At(@I, 2);
end;
```