# Delphi problems converting VirtualProtect EAT hook routines from C to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, api, hook

I'm trying to convert this code which came from [CHook](http://www.uc-forum.com/forum/c-and-c/60351-iat-eat-hook-annotations.html) forum posting this code which does EAT hooking:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <string>

#if PSAPI_VERSION == 1
#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi.lib")
#endif

template <typename DestType, typename SrcType>
DestType* ByteOffset(SrcType* ptr, ptrdiff_t offset)
{
        return reinterpret_cast<DestType*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(ptr) + offset);
}

bool eat_hook(void* old_function, void* new_function)
{
        HMODULE hModule;
        GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (LPCSTR)old_function, &hModule);

        PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER DosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModule;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeader = ByteOffset<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS>(DosHeader, DosHeader->e_lfanew);
        if (IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE != NtHeader->Signature)
        {
                MessageBox(0, "Bad NT header signature", "Error", 0);
                return false;
        }

        PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY ExportDirectory = ByteOffset<IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY>(DosHeader,
                NtHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);

        DWORD* functions = ByteOffset<DWORD>(DosHeader, ExportDirectory->AddressOfFunctions);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ExportDirectory->NumberOfFunctions; ++i)
        {
                if (functions[i] == (DWORD)old_function - (DWORD)hModule)
                {
                        DWORD oldProtection;
                        if (!VirtualProtect(functions + i, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection))
                        {
                                MessageBox(0, "VirtualProtect failed", "Error", 0);
                                return false;
                        }

                        functions[i] = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(new_function) - reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(DosHeader);

                        if (!VirtualProtect(functions + i, sizeof(DWORD), oldProtection, &oldProtection))
                        {
                                MessageBox(0, "VirtualProtect failed", "Error", 0);
                                return false;
                        }

                        return true;
                }
        }

        return false;
}

bool iat_hook(void* old_function, void* new_function)
{
        HMODULE hModule;
        DWORD sizeNeeded;
        if (0 == EnumProcessModules(GetCurrentProcess(), &hModule, sizeof(hModule), &sizeNeeded))
        {
                MessageBox(0, "EnumProcessModules failed", "Error", 0);
                return false;
        }

        PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER DosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModule;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeader = ByteOffset<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS>(DosHeader, DosHeader->e_lfanew);
        if (IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE != NtHeader->Signature)
        {
                MessageBox(0, "Bad NT header signature", "Error", 0);
                return false;
        }

        PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR ImportDirectory = ByteOffset<IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR>(DosHeader,
                NtHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);

        for (size_t i = 0; ImportDirectory[i].Characteristics; ++i)
        {
                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA thunk = ByteOffset<IMAGE_THUNK_DATA>(hModule, ImportDirectory[i].FirstThunk);
                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA origThunk = ByteOffset<IMAGE_THUNK_DATA>(hModule, ImportDirectory[i].OriginalFirstThunk);

                for (; origThunk->u1.Function; origThunk++, thunk++)
                {
                        if (thunk->u1.Function == (DWORD)old_function)
                        {
                                DWORD oldProtection;
                                if (!VirtualProtect(&thunk->u1.Function, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection))
                                {
                                        MessageBox(0, "VirtualProtect failed", "Error", 0);
                                        return false;
                                }

                                thunk->u1.Function = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(new_function);

                                if (!VirtualProtect(&thunk->u1.Function, sizeof(DWORD), oldProtection, &oldProtection))
                                {
                                        MessageBox(0, "VirtualProtect failed", "Error", 0);
                                        return false;
                                }

                                return true;
                        }
                }
        }

        return false;
}

bool hook(void* old_function, void* new_function)
{
        return eat_hook(old_function, new_function) && iat_hook(old_function, new_function);
}
```

From c++ to Delphi, but I'm with problems at var declarations, specifically the "functions" var.

This is my Delphi-converted INCOMPLETE code:

```
function eat_hook(old_function, new_function:pointer):boolean;
var
 Module: HMODULE;
 DosHeader: PImageDosHeader;
 NtHeaders: PImageNtHeaders;
 ExportDirectory: PImageExportDirectory;
 functions: PDWORD;
 i: size_t;
 oldProtection: DWORD;
begin
 GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, pointer(old_function), Module);
 DosHeader := PImageDosHeader(Module);
 NTHeaders := PImageNtHeaders(DWORD(DOSHeader) + DWORD(DOSHeader^._lfanew));
 if IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE <> NtHeaders.Signature then begin
   MessageBox(0, 'Bad NT header signature', 'Error', 0);
   exit;
 end;

 ExportDirectory := PImageExportDirectory(PAnsiChar(DosHeader) + NtHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);
 functions := PDWORD(PAnsiChar(DosHeader)+dword(ExportDirectory.AddressOfFunctions));

 for i:=0 to ExportDirectory.NumberOfFunctions do begin

  if not VirtualProtect(functions, sizeof(dword), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @oldProtection) then begin
   MessageBox(0, 'VirtualProtect failed', 'Error', 0);
   exit;
  end;

  functions[i] := DWORD(new_function) - DWORD(DosHeader);

  if not VirtualProtect(pointer(functions), sizeof(dword), oldProtection, @oldProtection) then begin
   MessageBox(0, 'VirtualProtect failed', 'Error', 0);
   exit;
  end;

 end;

end;
```

The line which attempts to assign to `functions[i]` results in a compilation error:

```
[DCC Error]: E2016 Array type required
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you use the C++-builder to compile the C++ Code and create a delphi interface?

Comment: I hereby promise to downvote and vote to close on all "Please convert teh codez" questions.  Not enough effort shown by the OP.

Comment: @Warren I give you comment a virtual downvote. paulohr is brand new to SO and should be shown some slack. What's more paulohr has responded very well to all requests for clarification and has made considerable effort, witness the converted Delphi code. I think we should try to help people like paulohr.

Comment: Well, I think this question can be rescued by editing.  I fixed the title, so it's not a pure question-on-conversion but perhaps (if someone helps him out) a really valuable bit of hooking code.

Comment: This is nearly a dupe of the question asked yesterday by the same guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466704/eat-hook-in-delphi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that you are writing to the array `functions` in sequential order and increment the pointer rather than use array indexing.

```
functions := PDWORD(PAnsiChar(DosHeader)+dword(ExportDirectory.AddressOfFunctions));
for i := 0 to ExportDirectory.NumberOfFunctions-1 do begin
  if not VirtualProtect(functions, sizeof(dword), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @oldProtection) then begin
    MessageBox(0, 'VirtualProtect failed', 'Error', 0);
    exit;
  end;

  functions^ := DWORD(new_function) - DWORD(DosHeader);

  if not VirtualProtect(functions, sizeof(dword), oldProtection, @oldProtection) then begin
    MessageBox(0, 'VirtualProtect failed', 'Error', 0);
    exit;
  end;

  inc(functions);
end;
```

The trick here is that each time round the loop `functions` points to the i<sup>th</sup> item in the array. When each iteration is done the `inc(functions)` advances the pointer on to the next item, ready for the next iteration.

I also corrected your `for` loop. In your Delphi code you performing one iteration too many.

Comment: It's nice that you made the effort to answer, but I really think the OP should not be encouraged (nor the 10K people after him/her) to just ask "convert me dis C++ codez plz kthxbye".

Comment: @WarrenP OP is clearly struggling and doesn't have a strong understanding of C++. Surely we are here to help. At least I have tried to explain the code a little and you will see that at the previous question, I refrained from converting the code. At least until OP tried and came up with something that was wrong.

Comment: @paulohr Your `for` loop is still wrong. And as for whether or not the code is correct, I've not reviewed it in enough detail to say. I've just tried to answer the immediate questions and anything else that I happened to spot. You should check and double check the code.

Comment: But is StackOverflow a better site for containing a permanent record of 8 million or so "convert this header to Delphi"?  My feeling is that if we ask the OP to restate their real single problem (How do you thunk like this, but in pascal?) we get more signal, and less noise, and everybody wins.

Comment: +1. An extra comment for the OP. In C/C++ arrays and pointers are interchangeable. `myArray[i]` is equivalent to `*(myArray+i*itemSize)`. As @David advised to do in Pascal. By contrast Pascal is more strict so it doesn't let you treat a pointer automagically as an array. You have to do the trick explicitly.

Comment: @Warren: I agree with you but I'm afraid there's no nicer way to treat these Windows calls... are there?

Comment: @WarrenP I personally don't really care about whether or not SO is better or worse for questions like this. We are about to pass 10 million posts on SO. It's full of all sorts of junk! I know that Jeff and Joel have this idea that SO will be some amazing repository of sage wisdom. It might be that, but it will inevitably always contain lots of Qs like this. I'd rather just help people.

Comment: Fine enough.  But think not just of this person, but of the next 20 after him who ask instead of "my variable don't works", the same exact question, but they say instead "it crashes, plz helps".  If we encourage people to ASK SMART, it benefits everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this page entitled [Win32 CodeHook - an open source library for binary code hook and redirect for Win32 Delphi and C++](http://www.kbasm.com/codehook.html).

You can find the source code of the unit **CodeHookIntf.pas** [here](https://bitbucket.org/magnomp/emballo).

[DelphiMVP](https://bitbucket.org/magnomp/delphimvp/overview) is an sample demo using **CHook.dll**.

I have harnessed Emballo and DelphiMVP with Delphi XE: it works!

Notice [Magno Machado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888361/magnomp) the author of Emballo is a SO member.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the best way to approach the problem is to actually look at what you're trying to do in C++ and find the existing library (already converted to Delphi) that does what you need.

For example,  the kinds of hooking you're trying to do here, are already done by `MadCodeHook` libraries, which are provided by [Madshi](http://madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm) here. They are now only available commercially, because they are very powerful, and he doesn't want to enable malware.

Comment: MadCodeHook hooks EAT or IAT?